# How to open keyboard if the device is in 'Tablet Mode'

Tags: c#, wpf

When clicking on a text field, automatically open up the Windows 10 touch keyboard if the device is in 'Tablet Mode'. 
How to Know  device is in 'Tablet Mode'?
How to open keyboard in WPF?

Comment: According to http://www.windowscentral.com/auto-display-touch-keyboard-windows-10-desktop-mode, this is a feature of the OS, not the applications.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think this is a misunderstanding. WPF doesn't run in tablet mode at all and doesn't have an on-screen keyboard. It's strictly a desktop-oriented technology. I'm assuming that you are building an applicant in XAML and that you want the same application to run in both places without having to create to separate projects.

WPF is a technology to run XAML in desktop mode whereas a different technology, called WinRT, is required to run applications created in XAML in tablet mode on Windows 10.

If you want to build a single application that is capable of running in both modes, you need to consider adopting an MVVM "framework" to help you out with this task.

The purpose of using MVVM in this context is that it enables you to separate your cross-platform "business logic code" inside classes called "ViewModels" while putting your UI specific code inside a XAML file with a different XAML file being created for each platform you are supporting (for example WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone, WinRT).

Here are some MVVM frameworks that can help you with this:

- Caliburn.Micro:
  (http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/windows-runtime)
- MvvmCross: https://mvvmcross.com/
- Catel: (https://catel.codeplex.com/)
- Simple MVVM: (https://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- MVVMLight: (http://www.mvvmlight.net/)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I want to simply identify my application is running on tablet mode or not.  if running on tablet mode then we will display keyboard.

Comment: I think this answer is confusing tablet mode (a Windows 10 concept) with the separation between desktop and immersive UI and apps that existed in Windows 8.x.